# Can we ban the satellites tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

This site is fundamentally about space, exploration, and satellites. As a result, most of the questions could be tagged with the [satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellites) tag. I think it should be banned entirely from the site.

In addition, [artificial-satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-satellites) should also be banned. However, tags with the word satellite might be allowed in, similar to how tags with the word space might be allowed, depending on their purpose.

EDIT:

After receiving the response I have, I realize I should clarify a bit more why I would like to see this. Any question about satellites should be about something else, such as orbit determination, thrusting, attitude, instruments, etc. Thus, satellites has the tendency to be somewhat of a crutch. For instance, here's every question that currently has the tag [artificial-satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-satellites). After doing this exercise, I realized that it's probably not as bad as I thought, but I do believe it is a tag that should be watched carefully.

- [Expression for density in the Thermosphere and Exosphere](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/expression-for-density-in-the-thermosphere-and-exosphere) This doesn't have anything to do with satellites.
- [What is the life expectancy of a geosynchronous satellite dependent on?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/what-is-the-life-expectancy-of-a-geosynchronous-satellite-dependent-on) This is about orbital lifetime, only barely applied to satellites.
- [Are artificial satellites completely sealed or open to space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/are-artificial-satellites-completely-sealed-or-open-to-space) This one is probably the best question that I find a hard time using other tags to describe.
- [How full is the geostationary belt?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/how-full-is-the-geostationary-belt) This one would be okay to use the satellite tag, although I don't like the tagging for the question.
- [What is the smallest operational artificial satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/925/what-is-the-smallest-operational-artificial-satellite) This is probably okay as well.
- [Which artificial satellites in lunar orbit are currently active?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/221/which-artificial-satellites-in-lunar-orbit-are-currently-active) This is a somewhat poor question question anyways, but

Comment: A free-flying interstellar probe is nobody's satellite :P Signed on behalf of Voyager Brothers.

Comment: Isn't a free-flying interstellar probe a satellite of the centre of the galaxy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the top-voted questions (https://space.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), very few of them have anything at all to do with "satellites." I don't see this as a tag intrinsic to the subjects discussed in this site.

The term itself is a bit ambiguous (satellites can refer to either a man-made object or natural bodies that orbit another). The [artificial-satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-satellites) tag attempts to differentiate between the two meanings.

Answer (score 5):

I would (respectfully) disagree. Satellites are only a part of what we do here - a big part, sure, but that doesn't mean they are necessarily intrinsic. Just as Meta Stack Overflow has a few major, over-arching tags, and Stack Overflow itself has several, I would say we can keep it.

Answer (score -2):

It's an embarassingly strange question from the person who have made the idea of this site. I can't see the point. Satellites are singificant part of space exploration and the development of space technology. They have a "golden" place in this site, I think. =)

Comment: That's actually my point. Extremely common tags are usually banned as being tags, in this case, space and exploration. I think satellites should join that list... Maybe editing my question will help.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto It's a bit like banning c# or anything else from Stack Overflow. Or maybe, banning stack-overflow itself :D

Not all the questions are strongly related to space. Here's an example for myself =) http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/869/flying-on-dense-atmosphere-planets-moons